# Deriving inequality between two fractions that multiply to give a constant.

Tags: probability, fractions

There exists $r$ and $b$ such that:

$\frac{r}{r+b} \cdot \frac{r-1}{r+b-1} = \frac{1}{2}$

I understand that from this, we can imply that:

$\frac{r}{r+b}\geq \frac{r-1}{r+b-1}$

But somehow the solution deduces without explanation that:

$\left(\frac{r}{r+b} \right)^2 > \frac{1}{2} > \left(\frac{r-1}{r+b-1} \right)^2$

I can't understand why the squared sign is introduced and how these two squared fractions are related to $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: If $xy=z$ then one of $x,y$ is at least, and the other at most $\sqrt{z}$. Since you know in advance which one of $x,y$ is bigger, your conclusion follows.

Answer (score 1):

$xy = {1 \over 2}$

Also, you already known that $x > y$. This has nothing to do with the given equality. It's simply because if you subtract 1 from both the numerator and denominator of a fraction, you get a smaller fraction.

$x > y$ implies $x^2 > xy = {1 \over 2}$ (multiplying both sides by $x$)

$y < x$ implies $y^2 < xy = {1 \over 2}$ (multiplying both sides by $x$)

You have a the desired inequality.

I have assumed $x,y>0$ here.